# Embed JavaScript/Action Wizard in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, scripting, jspdf, adobe-pdf-library

I have about a large number of PDFs with form fields. Is it possible to embed a JavaScript command/Action Wizard in the PDF that will save the PDF or email it to me once all fields have been completed? The ones completing the form only have Acrobat Reader by the way, so this would have to work without the completer needing to have the action wizard locally.

Comment: no, a PDF doesn't run javascript

Comment: @Bravo , PDF can run JavaScript...

Comment: not in my pdf viewers :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add an active element (button) to your forms, which do initiate the submit. An automatic submit is theoretically possible, but **extremely** bad practice.

The button you will add does not even need JavaScript, but you add the Action *Submit Form* and set your options. Users with a somewhat capable PDF viewer will then be able to submit the form.

Comment: thank you so much! This is better than the way I was going about it. Is there any way I can submit to a network server? the mailto option works fine but I would rather collect the PDFs on a network server or OneDrive folder

Comment: In the Submit Form dialog, you can chose what you want to send. One option is the whole document. As target, you can essentially use any valid and sensible URI (mailto: is one, but http: , ftp: , or file: and many more are possible; you just have to make sure that the receiving end knows what to do with it).